# Preview version of .NET Core is not showing up in Visual Studio 2017 15.9

Tags: .net-core

I wanted to try the .net core 3.0 preview. However after downloading the .net core 3.0 preview SDK, my VS 2017 15.9 didn't show the .net core 3.0 on target framework when I wanted to create a .net core asp.net web application or wanted to upgrade the .net core 2.2 web app to 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out and wanted to share here in stackoverflow. So if someone experience same issue and looking for solution, it can be found sooner and hope it helps to save their time.

From Microsoft:
"Starting with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9, we’ve changed how the Visual Studio tooling for .NET consumes .NET Core SDKs. Prior to this change, installing a preview version of the .NET Core SDK would cause all Visual Studio tooling for .NET Core to use that SDK because it had a higher version."

Please go to this Microsoft article for more article for more. [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/13/net-core-tooling-update-for-visual-studio-2017-version-15-9/)